# Unable to access Xmatters apis

Tags: curl, http-status-code-401, xmatters

I am trying to make a REST API call to know who is on duty. Every time I run this command I get 401 status saying, unauthorized user. I can login successfully using the Xmatters Web Interface.
Here is the API call I am making

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --user username "https://xxx.hosted.xmatters.com/api/xm/1/groups/groupId/calendar"
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To access the API, ensure the user has (at least) the "Limited Group Supervisor" role. *If* you've never done this before, here is how:

- *As an admin and using the website, navigate to the Users screen using the link near the top
  of the site*
- *Search for and select the user in question*
- *Select the Roles tab for that user*
- *Select the Roles text field and a list should appear*
- *Select Limited Group Supervisor (or appropriate role)*
- *Finally, click Save*

Your curl command can be as simple as `curl --user username "https://xxx.hosted.xmatters.com/api/xm/1/groups/groupId/calendar"`

API Doc: https://help.xmatters.com/xmAPI/#get-who-is-on-duty

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's wrong with your command, maybe you missed the GET or you do not need the header.

But this here should work

```
curl --silent -X GET    -H:"Authorization:Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZAo=" --url "https://blabla.hosted.xmatters.com"
```

A base64 string can be generated like this:

```
echo user:password | base64
dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZAo=
```

I would recommend a tool like [DHC (Chrome Extension)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-rest-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm) to test your URLs. You can also generate curl commands.